# как достать из модели один обьект в Context processor

Tags: python, django

Стоит задача вывести одно поле из модели в контекст процессор. Нужно прокинуть поле в котором будет фотография во все темплэйты. Как вывести из модели только один объект модели?

Модель:

```
class PageInformation(models.Model):  # модель компании
    img_page = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/page/', verbose_name='фото страницы', blank=True)
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Лозунг', blank=True)
    about_company = models.TextField(max_length=1000, verbose_name='О компании', blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, verbose_name='email')
    reference = models.TextField(max_length=1000, verbose_name='Справка', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.slogan}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'О компании'
        verbose_name_plural = 'О компании'
```

Контекстный процессор:

```
from .models import PageInformation
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def img_cont(request):
    return {"page": PageInformation.objects.get('img_page')}
```

Comment: Замените изображения текстом.

Comment: Всё готово, спасибо что уделяете время

Comment: `PageInformation.objects.get('img_page')` надо заменить на `PageInformation.objects.get(pk=...).img_page`. не забыв обработать исключение, если нужный объект не найден

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def img_cont(request):
    return {"page": PageInformation.objects.get(<field_name>=...)}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]